# How to get data from activity to fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-bundle

I am using Navigation Drawer in my project and the "Add" feature is in an activity which is called by fab. I need to get the data from the Activity to the Fragment.

I have already tried with bundle and the app crashes.

In my activity, AddTodoActivity.java file ->

```
date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //showDatePicker();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("1", "From Activity");
            FragmentList fragobj = new FragmentList();
            fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

            Fragment fragment = new FragmentList();
            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.screen, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }

            finish();
        }
    });
```

And in myfragment, FragmentList.java file ->

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),  this.getArguments().getString("1"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two instances of `FragmentList` there: `fragobj` and `fragment`.

You use `fragobj.setArguments()`, but then pass `fragment` to the FragmentManager.

I don't really know why you're doing that, but if you want to pass the arguments, you need to remove one of those instances, and set the arguments on the one that remains. I recommend just removing the `fragment` one:

```
//...
FragmentList fragobj = new FragmentList();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.screen, fragobj);
fr.commit();
//...
```

The null-check on the Fragment is also unnecessary. There's no way it could possibly be null.

Comment: Can you post the crash log then?

Comment: If I don't call call the Fragment from the Activity, and I manually open the Fragment, the app craashes with error...
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.mythio.ado.FragmentList.onViewCreated(FragmentList.java:35)

Comment: Well, yes, because you're not setting arguments on it if you don't call it from where you're setting arguments on it.

Comment: I am adding elements in a List from an Activity, the List is in Fragment. How do I do it? From your suggestion, I was able to make changes, but then I couldn't open the Fragment from the Nav-drawer.

Comment: If you're trying to modify a list in a Fragment from an Activity, you're doing it wrong. Use broadcasts or SharedPreferences instead.

Comment: Ok, so I need to make use of Broadcast, or SharedPreferences, so that the changes made will be visible no matter from where I transact the fragment. Right?

Comment: Yes. If you're going to be adding the Fragment over and over again, though, you should use SharedPreferences, so the changes stick. Just remember that when you use `SharedPreferences#getStringSet()`, you need to duplicate what it returns. You can't modify the Set directly. You can do `new ArrayList<String>(returnedSet)` to fix that.